# Is it possible to define 2 different NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription values for different screens?

Tags: ios, swift

My app needs location permission for 2 use cases: user route tracking and to show nearest shops. It's different screens and different user experience. I would like to show 2 different values of `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` but it looks like I can define only one.

Maybe there is a way to define 2 values? Or do something else to show user 2 different explanations on the system prompt?

Comment: You can only define one. You can combine them: "xyz needs your location to help you find the nearest outlet and to track your journey".  You can also display your own dialog before requesting location access to provide more information. If they have already provided location access the first time they access the other function you can display a dialog like "note that xyz will track your location during journies" or "xyz will use your location to find the nearest outlet" but this isn't mandatory; location is already approved.

Comment: You may want to consider different dialogs for the case where location is denied that explains the specific use case that is being blocked